# How can I get the parsed remote address when I use urllib open a host via python2.6?

Tags: urllib2, urllib, python-2.6

There is a requirement getting remote address when request a host.

In python3, the response received by urlopen I can get the socket, and by using `socket.getpeername()` I can get the remote address。 But when I use python2.6, the urlopen is completely diffrent with python3. I have no idea how can I get the remote address by python2.6.

Answer (score 0):

First get python `socket` object and then use `getpeername()`

`from urllib2 import urlopen
resp = urlopen("http://baidu.com")
print resp.fp._sock.fp._sock.getpeername()`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYkBT.png)